# How can I make a View's dimension stretch beyond the device dimensions?

Tags: titanium

I have a large image I would like to center in a `View`. I would like the height of the `ImageView` to take up 100% of device height, and whatever the width is to take up device width.

I don't want the images squashed to fit the width of the device, I want to see the center of the image and if any width is offscreen and invisible that's perfectly fine.

I've tried a few things but nothing works.

**EDIT: My answer below works for iOS, but I still haven't figured out a way to get this to work properly on Android. I used `ui.js` by FokkeZB:**

https://github.com/FokkeZB/UTiL/blob/master/app/lib/ui.js

**This does what I want it to do with my image, but it's unfortunately a little slow (image loads after screen appears. I suppose I can load all images upfront and apply them later.**

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing some simple math in this situation. Get height of the device:

```
var height = Math.floor(Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight);
```

Then I set the height of my `imageView` to height of device. Next I needed the ratio of my image:

```
var ratio = imgOgWidth/imgOgHeight
```

And multiply that by device height:

```
var imageWidth = height * ratio;
```

And my xml was set up like this:

```
<View clipMode="Titanium.UI.iOS.CLIP_MODE_ENABLED" height="Ti.UI.FILL" width="Ti.UI.FILL">
        <ImageView id="background_image" image="/images/myImage.jpg"/>
</View>
```

In my `.js` file I set my image width and height to the above. Works well! Probably different for landscape but this worked for my app which is locked to portrait.

Note: This is only working for iOS.